# Updating timestamp in mongo document for the second time causes ConflictingUpdateOperators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update records in my collection but it throws this error:
`{"ok":0,"code":40,"codeName":"ConflictingUpdateOperators","name":"MongoError"}`

The code executed perfectly for the first time but fails on the **second** execution.
The code I used is:

```
   let query = { 'status': 'Pending' };
   let update = {
        $set: {
            status: 'Approved',
            '_metadata.lastUpdated': new Date()
        }
   };
   return mongoose.model(collection).updateMany(query, update).lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

`"ConflictingUpdateOperators"`. This error comes when the payload contains the same field twice with different value.